# Dictionary containing with only Serializable objects

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, dictionary

I am looking for a way to ensure that only serializable objects are stored into a Dictionary in C#.

To be more specific I'm looking to do something similar to this:

```
Dictionary<String, ISerializable> serialDict = new Dictionary<String, ISerializable>();
```

The problem with this is that I cannot store primitive types like integers, booleans, or strings.

Is there a way to ensure that my Dictionary contains only objects which can be serialized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do this at compile-time, but you can do it at runtime. If you build your own class deriving from `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, then in the constructor of your class, you can check the attributes attached to the `TValue` type, and make sure `SerializableAttribute` is one of them, else throw an exception.

All of the standard primitive types (`int`, `bool`, etc.) have this attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, this makes more sense. I was hoping for a compile time solution but this will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to consider is that in classes that are serializable are tagged with the [SerializableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) as opposed to implementing an interface.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx):

> Any class that might be serialized must be marked with the
>   SerializableAttribute. If a class needs to control its serialization
>   process, it can implement the ISerializable interface.

What you would need to do is make your own class that implements the [IDictioanry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) interface and every time someone calls add, use reflection to check if the element passed in has a serializable attribute (and throw an exception if it doesn't).

Code would look something like

```
class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue> 
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> d;

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if( value.GetType().IsSerializable )
        {
            d.Add(key, value);
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
    .....
}
```

Comment: I like this solution as well, its just the thing I need for my project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    static SerializableDictionary()
    {
        AssertSerializable(typeof(TKey));
        AssertSerializable(typeof(TValue));
    }

    static void AssertSerializable(Type t)
    {
        if (!t.IsSerializable)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format(
                "{0} is not serializable", t.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If one wanted to store ints, booleans and strings in this Dictionary, what Type should be chosen as TValue?

Comment: @David Good point, +1. That's not supported. But I read the question as if the asker wanted to store one of these types, not a combination of them.

Answer (score 1):

One answer would be to create a SerializablePrimative wrapper class.

```
class SerializablePrimative<T> : ISerializable {
   private T val = default();

   private SerializablePrimative(T newVal){
       val = newVal;
   }

   public static boolean IsSupported(Object o){
       if (o == null){
          return false;
       }else{
          return IsSupported(o.GetType());
       }
   }

   public static boolean IsSupported(Type t){
       if (// you want to support* ...)
       {
          return true;
       }
       else
       { 
         return false; 
       }
   }

   public static SerializablePrimative GetSerializable(Object o){
       if (IsSupported(o)){
            return //Intstatiate via Reflection **
       }else {
            return null;
       }
   }
}
```

The rest is left as an exercise to the reader, but basically your creating an adapter to make these certain types "fit" your dictionary.

*See Also: [Types Supported by the Data Contract Serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx)

**See Also: [C#: Using Reflection to Instantiate a Generic Class in .Net](http://omegacoder.com/?p=38)

Comment: This seems like overkill given serializable classes (including primitives) are already tagged with the appropriate attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping your dictionary?

```
class SomeClass {

    Dictionary<string,object> d;
    // add ISerializable
    public void Add(string key, ISerializable value) {
        d[key] = value;
    }
    // add primitive types
    public void Add(string key, bool value) {
        d[key] = value;
    }
    public void Add(string key, int value) {
        d[key] = value;
    }
    // etc ...
}
```

In this way you are sure that only ISerializable objects and primitive types can be added.

Comment: Per MSDN documentation, objects only need implement the ISerializable interface if they want control the serialization process.  So no all serializable objects implement this interface.